# the meaning of srv records of kube-dns

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, srv

For some reason I need get srv records in kube-dns , below is what I got

```
[root@devo-ui-37mmn /]# nslookup
> set q=srv
> devo-ui.dev.svc.cluster.local.
Server:     10.254.0.2
Address:    10.254.0.2#53

devo-ui.dev.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 100 0 3339386563373339.devo-ui.dev.svc.cluster.local.
>
```

host **devo-ui-37mmn** is one of my pod, the query string **devo-ui.dev.svc.cluster.local** is the service in kubernetes
and devo-ui-37mmn is connect to the service.

So I think the record **3339386563373339.devo-ui.dev.svc.cluster.local.** is the same pod, but what is the meaning of digital data "**3339386563373339**" and how to convert the number to human readable data, thank you.